# htaccess - cakephp - with subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, routes, subdomain

I would like to know how can I do that:
First.. I'm using cakephp and hostinger host.

I have a website 'www.jsagon.com' and I create a subdomain, its name is plugins. 
plugins.jsagon.com, but it's giving an error "500 Internal Server Error" when I access it.
 I have read that this error is because of Htaccess and I don't know much about it.

My structure is:

```
   public_html
     app
     lib...
     plugins(subdomain)
       app
       lib...
```

My htaccess /public_html/:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: 500 Internal server error can mean just about any problem, not necessarily something with your .htaccess file.  I would make sure debug is set to 2, and then check your log files to see if it says anything more specific.

Comment: When I changed the htaccess the error disappeared and the subdomain worked .. but the main website stopped working :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Htaccess ( or + Cakephp)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21151875/htaccess-or-cakephp)

Comment: hi Jhonatan, i am facing same issue, how did you resolve?