# Htaccess ( or + Cakephp)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

I would like to know how can I configure a subdomain to a website.
Example
www.domain.com
subdomain.domain.com

How can I configure the htaccess to access the folder subdomain and use it

```
public_html
 app
 lib
 plugins
 vendors...
 subdomain
    app
    lib...
```

this is my htaccess

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
 </IfModule>
```

thanks

Comment: you want to install cakephp in the subdomain?

Comment: Yes! But the main cakephp and htaccess doesn't redirect me to my subdomain folder.. Giving error '500 Internal Server Error :('

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in public_html/.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond    %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !subdomain/
  RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]   

  RewriteCond    %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !subdomain/
  RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```